# modbus(watlow F4T) allow to be connected, but does not allow to be read

Tags: modbus

the mobus (watlow F4T) allows for connection, my pc use a static IP and watlow F4T is also using a static IP(192.168.0.222), it works well on another laptop or pc, but it could not work on one windows 7 laptop.

The modbus use a 502 port and I checked firewall, and using telnet 192.168.0.222 502 there is no error message, if I use a different port the telnet returns a connection failure, so I assume port 502 is open.

I use ModbusTcpTest130 to test, same setting, when I try to read something from watlow F4T, it always mentions "unable to do modbus read, please check the port setting", as different laptop would work, so I assume there is something special on this laptop, anybody has clue?

**update:**  I tried another pc, it works when I only use modbusTCP130, however, when I tried modbus poll (I forgot to close modbusTCP130 connection), it fails, then after close both modbus poll and modbustcp130, whatever I use modbusTCP130 or modbuspoll, both fail, so looks port not released?

Answer (score 0):

How you are closing the port?. Just closing down the terminal?
When you are not sure that your port is closed, I would suggest  rebout devices on both ends. Also make sure there are only one instance of terminal is running. 
It wort to try change communication port on device to different one, to make sure that, on PC that port is not being use with diff applications.